# Excel VBA - count an item if the first 3 character of a string matches the keyword

Tags: vba, excel

I need to count an item if the first 3 character of a string if the first 3 characters are "APP" (for example).
As shown below, I am able to count the item if it has the "APP", but what I want is only counting if the item has "APP" as the 1st 3 characters of the string.
I need a code like `if InStr(items, "APP") And take the 1st 3 character Then
        count_of_string = count_of_string + 1`

I don't know how to write that in vba. I have seen something like `str2 = Left(str1,3)` but it's giving me 0 as results.

[image]

Here is my current code. Thank you.

```
Public Sub TEST()
Dim a As String
Dim row_number As Long
Dim count_of_string As Long
Dim items As Variant


row_number = 0
count_of_string = 0
Do

row_number = row_number + 1 
items = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_number)
    If InStr(items, "APP") Then
        count_of_string = count_of_string + 1
    End If
Loop Until items = ""

Range("A1").Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastcell = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "APP  " & count_of_string


End Sub
```

Comment: `If Left(items, 3) = "APP" Then`

Comment: i agree with using `left` funciton

Comment: Great it works!

Comment: Of course, you could just use the Excel `COUNTIF` function to achieve the same thing:  `="APP  "&COUNTIF(A1:A5,"APP*")`

Comment: You can use `Instr` function as well by slightly modifying the construct like `If InStr(items, "APP") = 1 Then`. "= 1" part will check if it is in the first position or not.

Comment: ahhh got it. Thanks @ShrivallabhaRedij

Comment: The other issue (may not necessarily be) that I see with the code posted is that it assumes all cells will be filled consecutively. e.g. if `A1,A2,A3,A5` cells had data and `A4` was blank then macro will stop at `A3` and will (possibly) give erroneous results.

Comment: @Jonathan Can you please accept my answer by clicking the button below the up/down vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the case of APP (i.e. not app) is important then you can use `FIND`, otherwise the `COUNTIF` that @YowE3K suggests in his comment (should add it as an answer).
Saying that, someone's going to show how to do it with a formula that is case sensitive in a minute.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim count_of_string As Long
    Dim rItem As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)

        'Find the first occurrence in column A.
        Set rItem = .Find(What:="APP*", _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=True)
        If Not rItem Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAdd = rItem.Address
            'Find the following occurrences until the code reaches the first instance again.
            Do
                count_of_string = count_of_string + 1
                Set rItem = .FindNext(rItem)
            Loop While rItem.Address <> sFirstAdd
        End If

        .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3) = "APP " & count_of_string

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use the `Left` function which can be used like this.

> Left(yourString, length)

This can be used to get the 3 first characters of the text in your case and then you'll be able to test these characters.

In your code, it'd do something like that:

```
Public Sub TEST()

    Dim a As String
    Dim row_number As Long
    Dim count_of_string As Long
    Dim items As Variant

    row_number = 0
    count_of_string = 0

    Do
        row_number = row_number + 1
        items = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_number)

        'Check if the 3 first characters are APP
        If (Left(items, 3) = "APP") Then
            count_of_string = count_of_string + 1
        End If
    Loop Until items = ""

    Range("A1").Select

    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    lastcell = ActiveCell.Address

    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "APP  " & count_of_string
End Sub
```

Comment: how about if I want to search a specific word in a string. For example: I have a dog. I want to count the word have in every row.